# What's the best way to create an ios app on windows 7?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I downloaded Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio, but I still don't see any options in either of those programs for programming iOS apps.  Is programming for iOS even possible on a PC?

Answer (score 1):

Using Xamarin with a business license, you can use Visual Studio on a PC for development, but you MUST have a Mac running as a build server.  The iOS native SDK and Apple iOS simulator tools are only available on a Mac, and Xamarin depends on them as part of the build process.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a native iOS app using a windows based machine. iOS apps can be developed using XCode only and XCode can be installed on mac only.

So in simple words there is no "direct" way of creating an iOS app from windows machine. I guess you should have searched on google first before asking this question.

Comment: I am not saying that we cannot create iOS native app without using XCode . my point was that it is the best IDE for creating iOS app because it provides things like storyboard, xib, interface builder, compiler, debugging tools, simulator n all

Comment: "Best" is a subjective term, I would certainly not choose to use Xcode if I had any other option (which I do).

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge : i would be glad if you could let me know about the IDE which you use.

Comment: Xamarin Studio. It has a compiler, debugging tools, simulator, and will soon have a storyboard designer too (it's in beta). At the moment storyboards/xibs are still supported, but edited using Xcode.